# Custom__obj__c: bad field names on insert/update call

Tags: managed-package, custom-object, permissions

We have a manged package which is installed by multiple user we are running a piece of code using salesforce rest API which update our custom objects at user account some user are updated perfectly while some are getting this error.

> Custom__obj__c: bad field names on insert/update call

So can anyone explain me why this error occurs is this some kind of permission problem on user end. Thanks.

Edit 1 : 
Is there some kind of query which could be run on developer console to check if their is some kind problem.

Comment: Can you update the specific field with the API user?  Login with that user and see if this is possible.  (edit: to be more precise, on the record that fails)

Comment: If some accounts work and some don't it feels like it could be a trigger/workflow issue. I would recommend reaching out to your package developer and ask them for assistance. If some users work and some don't then it's likely permissions. I would still check with the developer.

Answer (score 2):

Check that the profiles of the users that experience the error have access to the field on the object.  They cant update the field if they don't have write access to it.  Also worth checking if those users have access to managed package (do users need a license to access the managed package feature?)

Comment: how can we check this any suggestion?

Comment: Depending on you setup if you are using the advanced profile view, in the setup area search for Users, find the user that received the error, click on the profile link.  In the profile details page click "Object Setting" search for the object click on it and in the "Field Permissions" section see if the field has the Read and Edit permissions checked.  If not Edit and check it. If you are in the older profile view look for the object under the "Field-Level Security" section